# How can I write my own ef core function that operatoes on the database entitites

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

I am trying to add a new custom function to ef core that I can use on the database entites.

I need to add my own implementation of count on each entity.

```
db.xyz.count() does not work for me.
```

It does not work for me because its too slow owing to the number of rows.

I want to have a custom function which brings the counts from another view.

something like:

```
db.xyz.customcount();
```

I tried using ef core extension methods:

```
namespace xyz.Helpers
{
    public static class CustomCountExtension:DbContext
    {
        public static int CustomCount() => {....};

    }
}
```

But this function , I need it to query against a different view which has the counts of each entity stored.

.i.e

**Myview:**

```
table | row  |
______________

xyz   | n    |
```

> when i call xyz.customcount() , I need it to return rowcount where table
>   = xyz.

is this possible.

Is there a better of implementing the above idea?

**I am using:**

.net core 2.1
ef core 2.2

Answer (score 0):

You can map an Entity directly to your View and query it like a table.

```
public class MyView
{
    public string Table { get; set; }
    public int Row { get; set; }
}
```

Then define it as a `DbQuery` instead of `DbSet` in your `DbContext`:

```
public virtual DbQuery<MyView> MyView { get; set; }
```

Then map it to your View in the `OnModelCreating()` method using `.Query()` instead of `.Entity()`:

```
protected override view OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBulder)
{
    //... Other tables

    modelBuilder.Query<MyView>(query =>
    {
        query.ToView("MyView");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am looking for something that goes in hand with the entites. a custom function that I can use with ef core funcitons such as count(),include() etc...
Need to be able to use it on any entity